# On android how would I create a class that extends Location Listener so that both my main activity and Intent Service can use the same object?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, location, object-persistence

So I'm planning create an app that needs to obtain the user's location and it's going to have a class called `LocationController` that implements the `LocationListener` interface.

What I want to achieve is that as soon as the the main activity (call it `MainActivity` for now) is started (in its `onCreate` method) to call my `LocationController` object and have it start getting location fixes and updates.

However, I also need to implement an IntentService or Service that will continue running even after the main activity is shut down (i.e. called `onPause` and or `onStop`) and this service needs to access the very same `LocationController` object that the main activity started in the `onCreate` method to obtain some location readings.

Now, I've spent some time looking at how to pass data to from an activity to a service and looked at `Serializable`, `Bundle` and `Parcel` objects and none of them can pass `LocationListener` or `Location` objects so that's not much of an option for me (unless I missed something, in which case, I'm open to suggestions).

The other option I thought about was maybe with static objects. Basically, have the `LocationController` be a static class so that the `MainActivity` can call its methods to start getting location fixes but so that it also continues to exist even after `MainActivity` had been terminated. However, I'm still fuzzy about how to do this. For example do I make my entire `LocationController` a static object or do I make some of its methods static?

Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE**:

So I took **kabuko's** advice and wrote the following on the main activity class:

```
public void setLocationController() {
    if (locationController == null)
        this.locationController = new LocationController(this);
}
```

and

```
public static LocationController getLocationController() {
    // make sure to have called setLocationController() early in your
    // activity's life. onCreate is a good place
    return this.locationController;
}
```

, which, sets a creates a Singleton, but to access the Location Controller in my IntentService class (call it `MyService`), I accessed the location controller as a static member of the main activity class like so:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    private LocationController locationController = null;

    public MyService() {
      super("MyService");
      locationController = MainActivity.getLocationController();
      ...
    }

....

}   // end of class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a singleton instance of your `LocationController` class which is essentially "making your entire `LocationController` a static object". Just keep in mind that with your activity stopped, your service is the thing that maintains the lifetime of your application. If you want it long-running and handling multiple "tasks", you might want to be careful with `IntentService` which shuts down once it's out of work (possibly killing your app and your singleton).

Answer (score 1):

better have a service, register a locationlistener in it, and pass the location updates to Activity by sending broadcast intent, through receiver.